# RecyclerView: toggling visibility of a children of all visible rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, visibility

I have an Horizontal RecyclerView.
What I would like to do, is, at runtime, to hide 2 TextViews of all items from adapter.

So, What I would like to do, is to cycle through all visible items, get their layout, and then change visibility of some TextViews inside each children.

You can see it as a "simple layout" Vs "Complex layout" toggle.

I know that I should retrieve RecyclerView children through the assigned RecyclerView.Adapter, but is that really the best solution?

Thank a lot for any help.

My code:

```
public ViewHolder(View v) {
    super(v);
    // Some logic here to find children
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get the adapter here, loop all visible children, and change visibility?
            // Following line will do for clicked item only:
            tvwind.setVisibility(tvwind.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

From the above code, I can change visibility of clicked item, but not to all visible items.

Comment: Maybe try getting the child count of the row and use childAt() and toggle visibility?

Comment: Thank a lot, I tried to modify OP and explain better, but my problem would be to cycle through all rows and do this operation.

Comment: Now I understand better, You can try using a variable to check visibility on/off and use that variable inside onBindViewHolder, and then call notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: OMG! My code was inside ViewHolder constructor, not inside onBindViewHolder.. Must be too tired, I will gladly accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed this can be achieved by toggling visibility inside onBindViewHolder() of the Adapter.

Comment: Negative effect of this: List will scroll to position 0 and lost current position.

Comment: @Waza_Be: You can save the position and call setSelected()